# python fido2 server with if statement

Tags: javascript, python, fido, yubikey

I'm using the [this](https://github.com/Yubico/python-fido2/tree/main/examples/server) example as inspiration for my project about Yubikey. At the end of `authenticate.html`, I want to add an if-statement. So if the authentication is successfull redirect to a specific page, and otherwise recirect back to the homepage.
I've tried different places for the if-statement:

```
.then(function(response) {
  var stat = response.ok ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
  alert('Authentication ' + stat + ' More details in server log...');
}, function(reason) {
  alert(reason);
}).then(
  function() {
    if(stat=='successful'){
      window.location.replace('https://google.com')
    }
    else {
      window.location = '/';
    }
});
}
```

and

```
.then(function(response) {
  var stat = response.ok ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
  alert('Authentication ' + stat + ' More details in server log...');
  if(stat=='successful'){
      window.location.replace('https://google.com')
    }
    else {
      window.location = '/';
    }
}, function(reason) {
  alert(reason);
}).then(
  function() {
});
}
```

I've never seen Javascript before, but it seemed that I couldn't get around Yubikey and Python (I'm familiar with python) not using JS. None of the above has worked the intented ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you're using fetch then the correct (and simplest) way of handling this would be something like the following:

```
fetch('some-super-secret-endpoint')
.then(response => {
    if(response.ok)
        window.location = 'https://google.com'
    else 
        window.location = '/'
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
})
```